# Allow m3u files to be edited in TextEdit, saved, and used without a "is damaged and can't be opened" message

Tags: mac, security, textedit, playlist

I am using OS X El Capitan.

I edit the `.m3u` files that are playlists with TextEdit. After editing and trying to play the playlist files I receive the "is damaged and can't be opened" message.

I can get around this by adjusting the whole system security (system preferences -> security and privacy) to allow apps downloaded from anywhere but I'd like to somehow set `.m3u` files to be editable without security concerns instead of changing the whole system to be less secure.

How can I get the `.m3u` extension to be ignored by this type of security.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.m3u` files are really nothing more than just basic plain text files. My guess is that you're getting this issue because TextEdit is not currently set to use **plain text** as its format.

You don't specify what version of macOS you're running, but in the more recent versions of TextEdit you can change how it deals with file formats by default.

**Change the default TextEdit format**

You can change the default TextEdit format as follows:

1. Launch TextEdit
2. Go to **TextEdit > Preferences...** (or just use the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> shortcut)
3. Ensure you have the **New Document** tab
4. At the top you'll see three options for *Format*. Select the **Plain text** option.
5. Exit preferences

Now when you edit an existing `.m3u` file (i.e. it already has the .m3u extension) then it should be fine.

If you create a new file, be it a `.m3u` file or one in another format, you will need to manually add the extension to the filename when you save it. If not, it will default to the Plain Text extension (i.e. .txt) instead. You can also change this behaviour in Preferences by going into the **Open and Save** tab and unticking the checkbox for *Add ".txt" extension to plain text files*.

Comment: What is it using instead? Considering that it's a *text editor*.

Comment: By default recent versions of TextEdit use the Rich Text Format (.rtf). However, via preferences you can change this to Plain Text (.txt) and also set how TextEdit should behave in relation to other files such as HTML files (e.g. should it display HTML files as *formatted text* or as *HTML code*.